# Is there no linux system call or glibc function that copies files?

Tags: linux, system-calls, glibc

For copying a file, is there no Linux system call? Neither is there a function in GNU C Library? How is copying file implemented based on Linux system calls or GNU C Library then? Thanks.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html

Comment: No research effort at all. It's open source. Read the ‘cp‘ source.

Comment: IMO this is a valid question, and certainly not off-topic. it is not "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". Also, the answer given by @Employed_Russian is a very good answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

> For copying a file, is there no Linux system call?

No. One isn't necessary, and would be counter-productive if it existed. Just think about all the possible error conditions that could happen in a copy operation, and what appropriate response should be.

> Neither is there a function in GNU C Library?

It's *too trivial* a function to be useful and included in the C library (when there are no errors) and too complicated to make generally useful when there *are* errors. Specifying what should happen when there are errors is best left to the application, because only the application knows what should really happen.

> How is copying file implemented based on Linux system calls or GNU C Library then?

With `read` and `write` system calls.

Comment: `strlen()` is even more trivial, yet it is included.

Comment: @smoku `strlen` is *very* far from trivial (if you want it to be fast).

Comment: Exactly as "trivial" as hypotetical `fcopy()` - breaks when "if you want it to...". Makes the point even stronger.